# About the algebraic character of the solution of $\cos x=x$

Tags: trigonometry, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

The equation $x=\cos x$ is well-known because some facts. For example, with an old calculator, you can find approximations of the solution by typing any number and pressing the $\cos$ button repeatedly.

With Bolzano-Rolle combo, it is not difficult to show that this solution exists and is unique.

My question: **Is there some work about the rationality or trescendality of this solution**? Of course, $x$ is in radians.

Comment: You should think of it as intersection of two graphs: $ y=cos(x) \wedge y=x $. This allows determining if point (x,y) is inside the solution.

Comment: @ajotatxe Cf. [Is sin(x) necessarily irrational where x is rational?](/q/299124).

Comment: $\cos x$ is the real part of $e^{ix}$. If $x$ is nonzero algebraic, then so is $ix$, so $e^{ix}$ is transcendental, so $\cos x$ is transcendental, so $\cos x\ne x$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

Comment: Also known as "the Dottie number".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the solution is algebraic, then both $x$ and $\cos x$ are algebraic. This implies $\sin x=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}$ is also algebraic. So $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$ is also algebraic, which is not possible for any non-zero algebraic $x$ by [Lindemann-Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

Hence the solution is transcendental.